# Bash script syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'mwaa_bucket'")

Tags: bash, syntax

what I need to do is to read the key variable from the yaml file and echo the value. Therefore I wrote the following script (copys3.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '-------- Listing Git Cloned Repository --------------'
ls -ltr ${WORKSPACE}
echo '-------- Copying Airflow DAGS to S3 --------------'
echo ${action['mwaa_bucket']}
echo ${action['user_name']}
```

Here's the yaml file:

```
block1: 
    message: "Deploy DAGs to S3"
    action-type: business-logic
    agent-name: default
    mwaa_bucket: "com-mwaa-test"
    user_name: "dev"
    binary-location: "ApplicationConfiguration/copyS3.sh"
```

Both script as well as config.yaml are located into the same folder "Application Configuration"

The scripts produces the following error which I do not understand

```
./ApplicationConfiguration/copyS3.sh: line 6: 'mwaa_bucket': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'mwaa_bucket'")
./ApplicationConfiguration/copyS3.sh: line 7: 'user_name': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'user_name'")
```

Comment: Error message tells that there is no declaration of the array `action` in your code. Also you do not read from config fle.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg is right, you never called the file. What you can use is a combination of `awk` and `cut` to extract the info `WMAA_BUCKET=$(awk '$1 ~ /^mwaa_bucket/ {print $0}' <FILENAME>.yaml | cut -d '"' -f2)`. It is also unclear what you mean by `action`. You can also look at `yq` for yaml processing https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/